# MySql delete cascade effect on join table

Tags: mysql

I have a join table that maps a many to many object relationship.  There are two foreign keys in the join table

If I delete a record in a table that is referenced within the join table, is the corresponding mapped record also deleted?

Comment: This depends on your schema definition. Did you defined a cascade rule ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapped record is not deleted. ON DELETE CASCADE only goes one way: the record with the foreign key is deleted.

That is, if you have the keys set up like this, with table AB acting as the join table with foreign keys of both A and B:

```
 TABLE A   <==   TABLE AB   ==>   TABLE B
```

and you delete an entry from A, the corresponding entries in AB are deleted, but no entry in B.